# using file stored on aws s3 storage -- media storage as input of a process in django view

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I am trying to make my django app in production in aws, i used elastic beanstalk to deploy it so the ec2 instance is created and connected to an rds database mysql instance and i use a bucket in amazon s3 storage to store my media files on it.

When user upload a video, it is stored in s3 as : "https://bucketname.s3.amazonaws.com/media/videos/videoname.mp4".
In django developpement mode, i was using the video filename as an input to a batch script which gives a video as output.

My view in developpement mode is as follow:

```
def get(request):
# get video
    var = Video.objects.order_by('id').last()
    v = '/home/myproject/media/videos/' + str(var)
# call process
    subprocess.call("./step1.sh %s" % (str(v)), shell=True)
    return render(request, 'endexecut.html')
```

In production mode in aws (Problem), i tried:

```
v = 'https://bucketname.s3.amazonaws.com/media/videos/' + str(var)
```

but the batch process doesn't accept the url as input to process.

How can i use my video file from s3 bucket to do process with in my view as i described ? Thank you in advance.

Comment: what you mean _the batch process doesn't accept the url_ ?

Comment: The batch process take the video file name as input, in dev mode the video was on the file system so i gived the path of the video as input but now on the prod mode on aws i don't know how i can process a video stored on s3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not hard-code that string. There are a couple of things wrong with that:

1. "bucketname" is not the name of your bucket. You should use the name of your bucket if this would at all work.
2. Your Media File URl (In `settings.py`) should be pointing to the bucket url where your files are saved (If it's well configured). So you can make use of:

   video_path = settings.MEDIA_URL + video_name

I am assuming you are using s3boto to handle your storages (That's not a prerequisite though, it only makes your storage handling smarter and it's highly recommended if you are pushing to s3 from a django app)